# PHP Regex for replace alternative

Tags: regex

I have a requirement for which I am trying to find a regex pattern to replace the code. I understand that I can get normal regular expression for finding and replacing the text however reqirement is to find and replace the instance alternatively.

For example,

```
{code}
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' WHERE end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
{code}

Rollback: 

{code}
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' WHERE end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
{code}
```

This is the original text. I need to replace the first instance of the `{code}` to `<pre>` and the second instance of the `{code}` to `</pre>`

Expected result

```
<pre>
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' WHERE end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
</pre>

Rollback: 

<pre>
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' WHERE end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
</pre>
```

Any help on how to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP - search for the start and end `{code}` and capture the text between them, outputting it between `<pre>` and `</pre>`. We use a lazy match (`.*?`) to ensure we don't grab all the text between the first and last `{code}` in the input.

```
echo preg_replace('/{code}(.*?){code}/s', '<pre>$1</pre>', $text);
```

Output:

```
<pre>
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' WHERE end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
</pre>

Rollback: 

<pre>
UPDATE tenants SET end_user_uuid = '9e194bfeace6c2d17cc71cc15e84f93a' WHERE end_user_uuid = '32392464c8a19a15dd8dc982ae3d574b' AND instance_id = '265358' AND domain = 'automobieljansen';
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \{code\}(.*?)\{code\}
Replace: <pre>$1</pre>
```

### Demo

Note: I assume you would be able to run the above regex in dot all mode.  If not, then do the find on this alternative pattern:

```
\{code\}([\s\S]*?)\{code\}
```